# How do I write a function that takes an xml file and an integer value X as parameters and updates the attributes of the xml based on the given integer

Tags: python, xml, attributes

I am trying to write a function that will take as parameters my xml file file.xml and an integer I want to input from the keyboard.

My xml files looks like this:

```
<root>
<item name="A" days="10"/>
<item name="B" days="20"/>
```

I have the integer X :

```
X= int(input("X value is:")
```

I want to add the X value to the days attribute in my xml.

```
for X=1.1         =>I want the output:
A, 11.1 days
B, 20.1 days
```

I don't know how to write the function because when I tried calling it the name of the file I wanted to open was not recognized =>
    read_xml(file.xml)
NameError : name 'file' is not defined.

But more importantly, I don't know how to add an integer value to the attribute of an xml file.

What I did so far using the ElementTree library:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
tree = et.ElementTree(file = 'file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for item in root.findall('item'):
 names = item.get('name')
 ages = item.get('age')
 genders = item.get('sex')

 print(f'''\n{names}, {ages} years old''')
```

At this moment I get the desired output format but without the integer X added to the days attribute.
Please let me know if you have any idea how to solve this in Python3.

Thanks!!!

Comment: There are no 'age' and 'sex' in your XML example. Are you sure you run the code against your XML example?

Comment: 1.1 * 10 = 11 and not  11.1

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root>
<item name="A" days="10"/>
<item name="B" days="20"/>
</root>'''


def change_days_value(factor):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml)
    items = root.findall('.//item')
    for item in items:
        item.attrib['days'] = str(int(item.attrib['days']) * factor)
    ET.dump(root)


# read this value from the user
factor = 1.1
change_days_value(factor)
```

output

```
<root>
   <item days="11.0" name="A" />
   <item days="22.0" name="B" />
</root>
```